# Adding Binary number in java

Tags: java, binary

Guys please help me on my problem.On how did he do these. I only    know that first binary to decimal and then decimal to   binary but I don't know how he did these.Please help me guys if these is a similar thread.Please inform me guys.Thank you

```
  import java.io.*;
   public class BinaryAddition
    {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws Exception
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new            InputStreamReader(System.in));

     System.out.print("\nEnter number1: ");
     int num1 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
     int num4 = num1;

  System.out.print("\nEnter number2: ");
  int num2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  
  int num5 = num2;

int k = 1;
int dec1 = 0,dec2 = 0;

while(num1 != 0)
    {
  //This is the line that I don't really understand how he      did these.
        dec1 = dec1 + (num1%10) * k;     
        k = k * 2;
        num1 = num1/10;   

    }

k = 1;
while(num2 != 0)
    { 
        dec2 =dec2 + (num2%10) * k;    
        k = k * 2;
        num2= num2/10;     
    }

int num3 = dec1 + dec2;
String str1 = Integer.toBinaryString(num3);

System.out.print("\nAddition of " + num4 + " + " + num5   + " = " + str1);

System.out.println();
```

}
}

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: while(num1 != 0)
    {
  //This is the line that I don't really understand how he      did these.
        dec1 = dec1 + (num1%10) * k;     
        k = k * 2;
        num1 = num1/10;

Comment: I don't know what's the function of k,dec1 and num1..or what's there purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dec1 = decimal number representation of num1(binary)
k = binary factor
dec1 = dec1 + (num1%10) * k;
```

Here he is building the decimal number from binary number.

```
(num1%10) gives the last digit of the number.
Ex: num1 = 110
```

First iteration:

```
    dec1 = 0 +(110 %10) *1
    dec1 = 0
    k = 1*2
```

Second iteration:

```
dec1 = 0 +(11%10) * 2
dec1 = 2
k = 2*2
```

Third iteration:

```
dec1 = 2+ (1%10) *4
dec1 = 6
```

Finally the dec representation of `110 is 6`

Comment: @Radhaskrishna Pemmasani...Thank you so much sir..Now I understand it more clearly.Thank you so much sir.